# PHP: Using Backslash for refer to global space on namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I use a backslash to refer to the global method exactly.
I do not want to look it up in the namespace and find it in the global space.

Assistant tell me it's unnessary code.
and recommend convert it to import since few days ago.

**starts with backslash**:

```php
namespace Foo;
echo \is_numeric('1');
```

**guide to**:

```php
namespace Foo;
use function is_numeric;
echo is_numeric('1');
```

Is the first way will wrong at future?

Is the second way better than the first way about performance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Global Namespace Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449159/php-global-namespace-function)

Comment: Neither of these is necessary, just use functions as always. Don't waste your time worrying about nanosecond improvements, worry about maintainable and readable code. Your app could run for years before you save the amount of time it took to write this question.

Comment: @miken32 I almost agree to your opinion, but it was just one string
if it make effect with simple typing, are you not charming it as enough even in nano time?

Comment: Second example is just more DRY and clean, since it does not add unnecessary noise in code itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `is_numeric` like this, the best balance of performance and readable

```
namespace Foo;
echo is_numeric('1');
```